# How do you remove or merge the blank page that is created after a section break?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am creating a document which has various portrait and landscape oriented pages. I am doing this using section breaks, to allow portrait/landscape/portrait layouts and so on.

However, when I create a section break, it creates a new page, which is the 'new page' after the section break.

How can I merge this black page or easily delete it? At the moment I am leaving it in and copy/pasting pages into the new blank pages.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean that there is an empty blank page in the end of the document after the last section break? Could you maybe include an example screen shot?

Comment: Yeah, it creates a new blank page following the break. However I can't delete the empty space and get it to merge with the previous document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the next blank page has the orientation than the previous page, on which the section break (with page break) is located on, change the type of section break.

## Switch behavior after section break

Unfortunately, I have only available a German Word 2007 version in the moment. Therefore, I am not sure whether I give the correct English phrases.

While the cursor is on the new blank page, go to the `page layout` ribbon (green), click on `page layout` (orange) and switch to the `layout` tab (blue). At the top you can choose the behavior after the section break (New Page / Stay on Page / ...).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was the same for my English language version. I just selected new page and was able to move all of my items across. Just for reference for other people doing this, it is easier to add these in as you go along. I had to do it this way as I was updating some documentation to a new template, and therefore couldn't start from scratch.

Comment: @Sam Glad to help :-) . If this answer solved your problem please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Any idea as to why this process wouldn't work on a newer version of Word? I am using Word365.

Comment: @JCrosby This process should also work with newer versions of Word. I didn't have another MS Word Version available when I wrote this answer. I tested it in Word 2016 five minutes ago and it worked as well. Doesn't it work in your Word?

Comment: No, it didn't. But when I opened the document today the blank page was gone. The only difference between today and yesterday is about 1500 words.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I just ran into it. The problem occurs whenever you put a section break on two consecutive pages. Unfortunately although you can fix it by deleting one of the breaks you now have the problem of the header showing up. I worked around it by adding an empty text box without borders into the body of the page and moving it over the heading section. Don't add it to the header as that will add it to all headers. Frustrating. But it worked.